# How to access and instantiate a javascript class from TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, class, typescript

I'm using jsPDF and I've added its jspdf.min.js file on the page.

How can I use it from within a typescript class? jsPDF is unknown it complains:

```
  btnPrintReportClick() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.fromHTML($('.container').html(), 15, 15, { 'width': 170 });
        pdf.save('file_name.pdf');
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to give us more information for us to help you. In general, TypeScript requires that you have a *definitions* file for any JavaScript code you're including, since TypeScript overlays a type system on JavaScript. More: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the [definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jspdf) for it.

From your question I assume that you're loading `jspdf` simply by placing a `script` tag in your page, and in that case just add this [triple-slash-directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) to your typescript file:

```
/// <reference path="PATH/TO/jspdf.d.ts />
```